# Joins when multiple columns in one table refer to the same second table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I've been searching google all afternoon I'm not even sure how I would word the question I have so that google or bing might understand it. So I have 2 tables(the tables and the database setup were not my doing) one is the details of a product

```
name, value, weight, weight unit of measure id, length, width, height, dimensions unit of measure id, description
```

Then another table with the units of measure and their ID values

eg.

```
id, unit name
1,     cm
2,   inches
3,     lbs
4,     kg
5,    feet
```

I need to select from the products table, but replace the unit of measure ID's with the actual unit of measure text from the other table.

the data looks like

```
sm widgets, $10, 20, 3, 10, 10, 10, 1, small widgets
```

I want the results to come out like

```
sm widget, $10, 20, lbs, 10, 10, 10, cm, small widgets 
lg widget, $15, 50, kg, 10, 10, 10, inches, large widgets
```

thanks for any insight you guys can give me

Answer (score 1):

This is done with a `JOIN`.

NOTE: I'll assume your table are named `product` and `unit`; please replace those with the actual names if you try to use any of this.

If every row in `product` has a valid  weight or dimension unit of measure ID- that is to say, if none of the IDs is `NULL`, and all ID values actually exist in `unit` - then you can do this with an `INNER JOIN`.

If some rows in `product` have a `NULL` value in that field, or have a value that doesn't match the actual `id`s in `unit`, and you'd still want those product rows to show up in your results, then you need to use an `OUTER JOIN`.

I'll construct a demonstration query using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for both IDs. IF you have a row where the actual `unit` row can't be found, then that unit name will come out as `NULL`:

```
SELECT name
      ,value
      ,weight
      ,w_uom.[unit name] as [wt unit]
      ,length
      ,width
      ,height
      ,d_uom.[unit name] as [dim unit]
      ,description
  FROM product p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN `unit` w_uom ON (p.[weight unit of measure id] = w_uom.id)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN `unit` d_uom ON (p.[dimensions unit of measure id] = d_uom.id)
;
```

When joining to the same table twice, you *must* use a table alias so you can tell which joined table you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're selecting the Unit of Measure (UoM) id column instead of the value column.

So if your current query looks something like:

```
SELECT 
name
, value
, weight
, weight unit of measure id
, length
, width
, height
, dimensions unit of measure id
, description
```

You'll need to make sure you replace the [fimensions unit of measure id] column with [dimensions unit of measure VALUE] column